# Table Validation for my DateFrom and DateTo in MS Access

Tags: validation, datetime, ms-access

What can I put in my table to validate so my 'DateFrom' is always before my 'DateTo' so that I can get a popup box stating date from cannot be after date to?

I am currently playing with the Validation Rules and Validation text in the Table by using

```
 <="DateTo"
```

But it is not validating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access won't let you reference another field in the Validation Rule for a field.  Use the Validation Rule from the *table's* property sheet instead.

[image: Table Validation Rule property]

Make sure to enclose the field names in square brackets as illustrated.  Otherwise, Access may enclose them with quotes.  And that won't work because the rule would then be based on a comparison of two strings.

Also supply your own Validation Text message if you want something other than the error text Access displays when the rule is violated.